# TFS Git repository asking constantly for credentials on Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, git, tfs, cmd

Each time I try to pull changes from a git repository in TFS, I get the following error using the Windows Command Prompt:

> Method 'DeleteCredentials' in type
>   'Atlassian.Bitbucket.Authentication.Authentication' from assembly
>   'Bitbucket.Authentication, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
>
> Username for 'https://tfs.jll.com':

and the credentials are asked. I don't understand what an Atlassian library has to do with this.

git --version throws:

> git version 2.17.1.windows.2

Any ideas on what could be the cause of this?

This started happening after I updated git for Windows.

Comment: Do you have SourceTree installed? If so, is it the latest version?

Comment: No, I don't have SourceTree installed.

Comment: I actually have the same problem after updating to git 2.17.1.windows.2 and I don't use anything related to atlassian

Comment: I also have the problem, and I also believe it is due to `2.17.2`.

Comment: Raised a bug for this here: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1711

Comment: Having this problem again with git version 2.35.1.windows.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** Issue [was reported](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1711) and [has been fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/651). You can get the update for git credential manager [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.16.2).

I also think this is due to some bug on `2.17.2`. I am getting the same exact message. I guess we will have to wait for them to fix it.

There is a working workaround, though. Go to WSL and push from there. It works.

`wsl
git push`

Another alternative is to use an Ssh endpoint.